# Confused about the ERC721 implementation

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, erc165

This is the function, openzeppelin is using to check the ERC721recieve interface. What is the purpose of having  **ERC165** when we are checking the implemented interface by this method??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the code:

```
/// @notice Handle the receipt of an NFT
    /// @dev The ERC721 smart contract calls this function on the recipient
    ///  after a `safetransfer`. This function MAY throw to revert and reject the
    ///  transfer. This function MUST use 50,000 gas or less. Return of other
    ///  than the magic value MUST result in the transaction being reverted.
    ///  Note: the contract address is always the message sender.
    /// @param _from The sending address
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT identifier which is being transfered
    /// @param _data Additional data with no specified format
    /// @return
```

So it check if the contract knows of the erc721 transfer